# Path finding in real world maps with custom valuation function

Tags: algorithm, maps, path-finding

## Description:

Our customer interested in logistics wants automated path finding for his business. The issue is that each city, harbor, state, and country has different legal system with different politics for various goods. For example, some goods are forbidden to be transported through the country or fee applies on others, etc.

## Intention:

For a given transport of particular goods I need to find the best possible route with a respect to the known politics. If no such route exists, I have to find several the less problematic alternatives.

## Questions:

1. I believe that custom weights of nodes and edges in the graph disqualifies the public maps APIs. The quick search I made showed that no well-known API accepts custom valuation function. Am I right?
2. I thought that the path finding over custom graph is quite simple even with the custom valuation function. On the other hand, the real world maps are such a giant graph that only thinking about application of conventional algorithms seems silly. Should I think about this solution or is that too complicated and I should look at some other options?
3. The only thing I can think of to be possible is something like OSPF algorithm - divide the world into regions with their politics and then find the routes only through the possible regions. For these routes for each region find routes through states, etc. That means dynamically change granularity based on the supported geographical objects (countries, states, cities, ...) and slowly converge to the highest granularity, i.e., streets. The bad side of this approach is that it requires a lot of programming as well as lot of computation. Furthermore, I am not sure if maps with such granularity exist and are publicly available. Is this wrong way of thinking or is this too complicated?
4. What are other options? I could not figure out anything else.